# WPF - Event / Binding - Infinite Loop Issue

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm having an issue with a wpf project I'm working on where two controls seem to create an infinite loop.

I have two text boxes (TextBox1 and TextBox2) that take in input. When a user enters a number into TextBox1, an event fires a calculation which will then populate TextBox2 with some value. TextBox2 also can take input, which will fire a reverse calculation to populate TextBox1 with some value.

Because of the two events, when a text is entered into TextBox1, it seems to fire an infinite loop where each of the events and viewmodel changes keep firing off the other.

Does anyone know the best way to prevent this from happening?

Here's some sample code that produces a stack overflow:

code behind / viewmodel:

```
public partial class HelloWorldView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public HelloWorldView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private decimal _fahrenheit = 32;
    public decimal Fahrenheit {
        get { return _fahrenheit; }
        set {
            _fahrenheit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Fahrenheit");
            Celsius = _fahrenheit / 2;
        }
    }

    private decimal _celsius;
    public decimal Celsius {
        get { return _celsius; }
        set {
            _celsius = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Celsius");
        }
    }

    #region PropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    private void FahrenheitBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        _celsius = Fahrenheit / 2.1m;
        OnPropertyChanged("Celsius");
    }

    private void CelsiusBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        _fahrenheit = Celsius * 1.2m;
        OnPropertyChanged("Fahrenheit");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" Foreground="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>

        <TextBox Name="FahrenheitBox" Text="{Binding Fahrenheit}" MaxWidth="75" TextChanged="FahrenheitBox_OnTextChanged" />

        <TextBox Name="CelsiusBox" Text="{Binding Celsius}" MaxWidth="75" TextChanged="CelsiusBox_OnTextChanged" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post your code which does it?

Comment: @adminSoftDK - I'm afraid I can't. I'm doing this for a project at work and rules prohibit me from posting any in house code.

Comment: I've modified the original post to include an example of my problem. Could really appreciate how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem in our project as well, you need to stop the mutual updates, when you set TextBox1 from the UI your code should not Call the Setter code for TextBox2 property ,  you can set the backing field for that property and raise the PropertyChanged event seperatly.

**EDIT** please change your view model code in addition to the change that you did in your event handlers. this is a very common pattern for view model properties to prevent unnecessary events.

```
public decimal Fahrenheit 
    {
        get { return _fahrenheit; }
        set {
                if(_fahrenheit == value)
                { 
                    return;
                }
                _fahrenheit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); // removed property name , not needed
                //Celsius = _fahrenheit / 2; // removed , allready taken care in event
            }
     }

    private decimal _celsius;
    public decimal Celsius 
    {
        get { return _celsius; }
        set {
                if(_celsius == value)
                {
                    return;
                }     
                _celsius = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); // removed property name, not needed
             }
    }
```

Comment: Is that the only way to do this? I've set up a bunch of states in the xaml code behind to have events fire only when some other event is not already fired.

I feel like that this should be a common problem and a more elegant solution should exist.

Comment: I guess I may not understand what you are explaining, but I tried changing the backing field and raising the PropertyChanged separately, but still it is firing the events. I've attached an example of my issue in my original post. It produces a stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 0):

I havent testes this, but it should work like this

```
public partial class HelloWorldView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {
public HelloWorldView() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

private decimal _fahrenheit = 32;
public decimal Fahrenheit {
    get { return _fahrenheit; }
    set {
         if(_fahrenheit!=value)
       {
        _fahrenheit = value;
        Celsius = _fahrenheit / 2;
        OnPropertyChanged();//there is no need to pass a name, as your
      CallerMemberName deals with it
       }
    }
}

private decimal _celsius;
public decimal Celsius {
    get { return _celsius; }
    set {
        if(_celsius!=value)
       {
        _celsius = value;
        Fahrenheit = Celsius * 1.2m;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
}
```

You dont need any OnTextChanged at all